# Are these answers to the following statements related to algebra correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

(i) If $A$ is skew-symmetric, that is $A^T = −A$, then $\mathrm{tr}(A) = 0.$

True because a skew-symmetric matrix have $0$s along the diagonal.

(ii) If $n$ is odd and $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $\det(A) = 0$.

True for same reason as above.

(iii) If $A^3 = I_n$, then $\det(A) = 1$.

$A = I_n*A^{-2}$ hence $\det(A) = \det(I_n)*\det(A^{-2}) = \det(A^{-2})$ which is not necessarily 1.

(iv) If $A^2 = A$, then $A$ is singular.

$A^{-1} = A$ but as $A$ is singular the inverse doesn't exist so contradiction??

(v) If $n = 2$, then $A^2 − \mathrm{tr}(A)A + \det(A)I_2 = A^2 − \mathrm{tr}(A)A − \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(A^2)I_2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(A)^2I_2$ =0.

Is there a quick way to answer this?

Comment: Having only zeros on the diagonal does not  mean the determinant is zero, so your answer to (ii) is wrong.

Comment: For (iii) you have to find a counter-example, your argument is not complete.

Comment: For (iv), note that $A=I_n$ satisfies $A^2=A$...

Comment: Also, (iii) is actually true if $A$ is restricted to have real entries.  Because $A^3 = I_n$ means $\det(A)^3 = \det(I_n) = 1$, which means $\det(A) = 1$, $\det(A) = e^{2\pi i/3}$, or $\det(A) = e^{4\pi i/3}$.  The latter two aren't possible if $A$ is real.

Comment: Not only your reason is wrong in (iii), but your answer is wrong, too, unless you area dealing with complex matrices.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  As it is right now, part (v) is an eyesore and is basically the only thing preventing me (and possibly others) from posting a full response.

Comment: I've tried to correct the formula since before I had no clue what $1/2tr(A)^21/2$ was.

Answer (score 3):

(i) Is correct

(ii) The reason given is incorrect.

Note that for any matrix, $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$, if $n$ is odd and $A^T = - A$, then $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n \det(A) = -\det(A)$. The only number $x$ such that $x=-x$ is $x=0$.

(iii) See @tilper's comment, and @Thomas Andrews.

It is actually true if $A$ is restricted to have real entries. Because $A^3=I_n$ means $\det(A)^3=\det(I_n)=1,$ which means $\det(A)=1$, so $\det(A)=e^{2πi/3}$, or $\det(A)=e^{4πi/3}$. The latter two aren't possible if $A$ has real entries.

(iv) This is false, as @user40085 points out. $I_n$ satisfies the hypotheses but has non-zero determinant.

(v) If $n=2$, then $A^2−tr(A)A+\det(A)I_2  =0$.

This is true, see the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example).